# Get result using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I've already edit my question before.

I want get the all result from table.td `status`. But the result cannot show the actual or realtime result.

If of all the status `pass` the result status is must `pass` too and if the one of status get `fail` the result status is  must `fail` too but I've get the result status `undefined`

[image: it must be pass]
[image: it must be fail]
[image]

Comment: <select ... disabled>...<select>  When present, it specifies that the drop-down list should be disabled.... what do you get in your ajax success, when using console.dir(data)? please avoid images of code and error messages: Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image. Code should be included as text in the question itself: 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) on SO when asking a question?